# SharePoint Migration - InfoPath with modern and classic SharePoint Online sites - please clarify

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, migration

We are migrating a large site collection from SharePoint 2010 to Office 365 SharePoint Online, starting with a single site (for testing purposes).

The site collection uses InfoPath forms quite heavily. We will eventually move all these InfoPath forms to PowerApps/Flow but for now, considering the goal is to first get off SharePoint 2010 entirely, we'd like to be able to do that part at a later stage.

1. Is it true that InfoPath forms are not supported by the Modern Site experience and thus must use the Classic site experience? (or is this an assumption I have made?)
2. If I create sites in the Classic experience initially, what effort will it take to modernise them at a later stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending to above answer, adding couple of points for more broader picture.

Infopath form is not supported on Modern experience.
Efforts to convert classic site to modern sites would totally depends on list and library types you are using.

I would suggest you to use scanner available at below link which provides list/libraries which are not ready for modern interface.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-scanner

Documentation about scanner is at below link.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-lists-and-libraries-scanner

Migration needs to be properly planned, all the caveats should be considered. If you are putting something at later stage, make sure you have process in place for later moving to modern interface. Below are some entities which would need to moved to modern interface later.

1. List/Libraries.
2. Pages(webpart pages)
3. Wiki pages

Page transformation guidance is available at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages

Hope this helps...

Comment: You make some great points, thank you. Thank you for pointing out the scanner tool which I'd not come across before - this looks incredibly useful. This may be outside the scope of this question, but which other caveats, to your mind, should be considered?

Comment: Adding some links...https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/migrate-to-sharepoint-online

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e29c331c-d6e6-4ad4-a75f-d2afc072bd86/migration-planning-checklist-for-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Answer (score 1):

1.Yes, InfoPath is not supported in the Modern Site experience.

2.You can convert classic site to modern site by referring to the article below:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-classic-sites